# Force 100% CPU usage on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing

I have a C# ASP.NET app that runs some lengthy simulations and does so in parallel. Something like this...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myArray = new[] {450, 586, 879, 457, 657, 852, 407, ... };

        myArray.AsParallel().ForAll(DoStuff);
    }

    static void DoStuff(int number)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

When running locally, and on most of my servers (Amazon EC2 instances), executing this code utilizes 100% of the CPU. This is what I want. I need these large calculations to be completed as quickly as possible

1 of my servers is a [C3.8XLARGE](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)
Intel Xeon E5-2680 v2 (Ivy Bridge) Processor
vCPU: 32
mem (GiB): 60

On this server, CPU utilization never goes above 60% and runs very slowly.

What could be causing this to happen on only this server? How can I troubleshoot?

Comment: It sounds like this question is better suited for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @p.s.w.g "Server Fault is a question and answer site for professional system and network administrators". This doesn't appear to be about administration, it's directly related to programming. Seems fine for Stack Overflow to me.

Comment: 60% doesn't mean it is processed slower. Maybe the XEON is so much faster than your other servers that the CPU isn't the bottleneck anymore. This would either mean the real processing time is even faster or other hardware components create a bottleneck.

Comment: Does seem like a server admin issue as you're looking at assigning system resources to a running app.

Comment: Nope, this is not (yet) an issue for [sf]. You need to do much, much more debugging first. I've voted to reopen this.

Comment: do all servers/instances have the same specs?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is in the "ForAll" method and how it scales.

To have 100% CPU you should have 1 thread per core doing something very heavy.

The TPL internally creates tasks and has a default TaskScheduler class to handle the requests and delegate it to a thread pool. Maybe there are some lags there.

I'd create a different approach creating the threads or tasks manually (1 per core). If you still don't get 100% CPU, I think server fault is a good idea. Probably something related to physical/virtual machine or some throttling in the server.